# Why angular send request from each Child component?

Tags: angular, observable

I have `Parent component` which send request to api and get `Observable` object with list of Productions.
This object is pass to **four** `Child components`. The problem is that every `Child component` send request to the api (4 in total). How can I make it to send only one request from Parent and pass Production list to Children?

**Parent Component:**

```
  private productions: Observable<Array<Production>>;

      ngOnInit(): void {
           this.productions = this.productionService.getProductionList();
        }
```

**Example Child component:**

```
  @Input()
  productions: Observable<Array<Production>>;

      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        
          this.productions.subscribe(res => {
    
              // Do something with response body
    
        })
      }
```

[image: Console network and 4 requests from Children]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.productionService.getProductionList()` - this is an observable object and `.subscribe` will actually trigger the api request.

You are subscribing in each child components, that's why you see several requests.

Instead, you can subscribe in parent component and pass only the result to the children.

```js
private productions: <Array<Production>>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.productionService.getProductionList()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(productions => {
      this.productions = productions;
    });
}
```

Comment: Working well! But can you explain how pipe() and first() works in this case?

Comment: you know Observable is a stream, and the subscription is saved in memory. Usually api request just needs to get the api result and have to be unsubscribed. `first()` will complete the observable from the memory after you got the api response.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment `this.productions` variable holds a cold observable. So each subscription will invoke individual requests. There are multiple ways to make the observable hot so that each subscription doesn't invoke the request.

The most quickest way would be to pipe in a [`shareReplay()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay) operator with buffer 1 in the source observable. It'll create a multicast that holds the last emitted value. Upon subscription, the buffered value will be *replayed* to the observers.

Try the following

```js
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

private productions: Observable<Array<Production>>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.productions = this.productionService.getProductionList().pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```